# I dont understand this syntax error

Tags: python

I think I'm calculating the conversion from an integer to a binary number wrong.  I entered the integer `6` and got back the binary number `0`, which is definitely wrong.  Can you guys help out? Here's the new code.

```
def ConvertNtoBinary(n):

    binaryStr = ''
    if n < 0:
        print('Value is a negative integer')

    if n == 0:
        print('Binary value of 0 is 0')
    else:
        if n > 0:
            binaryStr = str(n % 2) + binaryStr
            n = n > 1
    return binaryStr

def main():
    n = int(input('Enter a positive integer please: '))
    binaryNumber = ConvertNtoBinary(n)
    print('n converted to a binary number is: ',binaryNumber)

main()
```

Comment: How is this related to windows? And since when is a `ValueError` a `SyntaxError`?!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call `raw_input()`. Right now you try to convert your prompt message to an integer which cannot work.

```
n = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer please: '))
```

Of course a `try..except` around that line would be a good idea:

```
try:
    n = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer please: '))
except ValueError:
    n = 0 # you could also exit instead of using a default value
```

Comment: Thanks, I cant believe I forgot that, now I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the word binary directly after that.  I dont understand why, if i'm just defining a variable.

Comment: @NateBUProgrammer: Maybe you forgot a `)`?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the actual error mesasge. Maybe you have mismatching parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In `n = int('Enter a positive integer please: ')`, you are trying to make an int out of the string 'Enter a positive...'. I would assume you forgot your `raw_input()`. You could either do

`n = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer please: '))`

or

```
n = raw_input('Enter a positive integer please: ')
n = int(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a arbitratry string literal to an int.  I think what you mean to do is call a prompt method of some sort that takes input from the user.